# Why a MultiAZ db.t2.small reserved instance costs two normailzed units?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a MultiAZ Aurora MySQL cluster with 2 db.t2.small instances, the Master and the Read Replica

Now I want to buy MultiAZ Reserved Instances for both db.t2.small instances but when doing the purchase I see that each Reserved Instance costs 2 normalized unitS

[image: Reserved MultiAZ db.t2.small Pricing details]

On the other hand if I choose SingleAZ which is not the case of my cluster, I get 1 normalized unit which is the corresponding size for a single db.t2.small instance

[image: Reserved SingleAZ db.t2.small Pricing details]

Why do normalized units and corresponding usage charges get duplicated for MultiAZ Reserved Instances? I did not find clear enough documentation on AWS pages [[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithReservedDBInstances.html), [2](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/reserved-instances/)]

Would a single db.t2.small Reserved Instance be enough to cover the entirety of both db.t2.small at my MultiAZ Aurora MySQL cluster or should I buy 2 db.t2.small Reserved Instances for it to be a proper "Reserved Instances Aurora cluster"?

PD: For both purchasing configurations I am specifying only 1 db.t2.small Reserved Instance and No Upfront payment

Comment: The costs are duplicated because you’ll have twice as many instances... One instance in AZ one, and one instance AZ two.

Comment: You mean the Reserved Instances will be 2 although I am specifying only 1 MultiAZ Reserved Instace? That 1 MultiAZ Reserved Instance counts as 2? That is my guess but I have not got confirmation of this, and as Reserved Instances purchases cannot be revoked I find it important to verify it properly before actually buying them

Comment: Yes. Each AZ is an independent data centre and when you select “Multi-AZ” you get instances in each of the selected availability zones. You will have multiple instances, for example you’d have one in say `us-east-1a` and one in `us-east-1b`, and therefore as you are using double the resources you’ll incur double the costs.

Comment: The only issue I see arising from what you are telling me is I could specify more than 1 alternative availability zone in which case the costs should triple when specifying that I want to buy a MultiAZ instance at RDS Reserved Instances, but RDS Reserved Instances does not seem to be referencing the actual amout of RDS instances I have deployed thus should have no way to know how many instances I need for my specific use case and it seems to be always doubling the amout of Normalized Units and of Usage Charges Why is it always doubling when I could have >2 instances at my MultiAZ deployment?

Comment: Yes, it will relate directly to the number of instances you have deployed/purchased. With AWS you pay for the resources you use or, in the case of reserved instances, the instances you reserve. It’s not always doubling. If you have instances in 1 AZ you pay for 1 normalized unit, in 2 AZ’s you’ll pay for 2 normalized units, in 3 AZ’s you’ll pay for 3 normalized units, etc. Important to note that if you buy reserved instances, you’re still charged for them even if you don’t use them.

Comment: What you say seems to make sense but I am specifying only 1 instance at RDS Reserved Instances and the normalized units are instantly doubling at Pricing Details as shown at the images in my question up above, when selecting that this is a MultiAZ instance and if I specify 2 instances the price is not changing hinting that for each instance I will pay that amount of normalized units i.e. 2 if I specify 1 MultiAZ RI as in my case and 4 if I specified 2 MultiAZ RIs Is my reasoning wrong or am I misinterpreting the normalized units shown at RDS RIs console?